# C# ¿Cómo mantener los datos de una Lista al pasar a otro Formulario?

Tags: c#, lista

Ya que me han encargado en la universidad trabajar con `List` antes de base de datos, ahora bien, tengo una clase llamada `Alumno` en la cual tengo una variable lista (`List<Alumno> Alumnos;`). Tengo un Windows Form el cual contiene un botón que lleva a una ventana en donde ingreso todos los datos de un alumno y los guardo en mi lista, puedo ingresar los alumnos que quiera, y consultarlos también, y me aparecen aquellos que he ingresado, pero eso eso solo cuando tengo aquella ventana abierta, si cierro aquella ventana los datos de la lista desaparecen (nota: no estoy terminando de ejecutar al aplicación sino que cambio de ventana) lo que quiero hacer ese: ir y volver de una ventana a otra sin que los datos de la lista desaparezcan.

Esto tengo en la clase `Alumno`:

```
class Alumno : Persona
{
    private Carrera miCarrera;
    private DateTime fIngreso;
    private  List<Alumno> misAlumnos;

    public Alumno()
    {
        misAlumnos = new List<Alumno>();
    }

    public Alumno(String id) : base(id) { }

    public Alumno(String id, String nombres, String aPaterno, String aMaterno, DateTime fNacimiento, Carrera miCarrera, DateTime fIngreso)
        : base(id, nombres, aPaterno, aMaterno, fNacimiento)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Nombres = nombres;
        this.Apaterno = Apaterno;
        this.Amaterno = Amaterno;
        this.Fnacimiento = Fnacimiento;
        this.FIngreso = fIngreso;
        this.miCarrera = miCarrera;

    }

    public Carrera Carrera
    {
        get { return miCarrera; }
        set { miCarrera = value; }
    }

    public DateTime FIngreso
    {
        get { return fIngreso; }
        set { fIngreso = value; }
    }

    public List<Alumno> Alumnos {
        get { return misAlumnos; }
    }

    public void addAlumno(Alumno nuevoAlumno)
    {
       misAlumnos.Add(nuevoAlumno);
    }

    public String egresoEstimado()
    {
        String egreso = "";
        egreso = Convert.ToString(FIngreso.Year + miCarrera.AniosDuracion);
        return egreso;
    }

    public bool siExiste(String id)
    {
        bool existe = false;
        existe = misAlumnos.Exists(alu => alu.Id == id);
        return existe;
    }

    public int EncuentraIndex(String id)
    {
        int index = misAlumnos.FindIndex(alu => alu.Id == id);
        return index;
    }
}
```

y en la clase `form` tengo esto:

```
public partial class P_Alumno : Form
{
    Carrera c = new Carrera();
    Alumno a = new Alumno();

    public P_Alumno()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        comboCarrera.DataSource = Carrera.Carreras;
        comboCarrera.DisplayMember = "Descripcion";
    }

    private Alumno alumnoNuevo() {
        String rut = txtRut.Text;
        String Nombre = txtNombres.Text;
        String apaterno = txtAP.Text;
        String amaterno = txtAM.Text;
        DateTime fn = calendarioNacimiento.Value;
        DateTime fi = calendarioIngreso.Value;
        Carrera carr = new Carrera("100","carreraCualquiera",120000,9);
        Alumno aluNuevo = new Alumno(rut,Nombre,apaterno,amaterno,fn,carr,fi);
        return aluNuevo;
    }

    public void blocDesbloc(bool bloc) {
            txtNombres.Enabled = bloc;
            txtAP.Enabled = bloc;
            txtAM.Enabled = bloc;
            calendarioNacimiento.Enabled = bloc;
            calendarioIngreso.Enabled = bloc;
            comboCarrera.Enabled = bloc;
            btn_ingresar.Enabled = bloc;
    }

    public void mostrarUno(String id)
    {
        int i = a.EncuentraIndex(id);
        txtNombres.Text = a.Alumnos[i].Nombres;
        txtAP.Text = a.Alumnos[i].Apaterno;
        txtAM.Text = a.Alumnos[i].Amaterno;
        calendarioIngreso.Value = a.Alumnos[i].FIngreso;
        calendarioNacimiento.Value = a.Alumnos[i].Fnacimiento;
        comboCarrera.Text = a.Alumnos[i].Carrera.Id;
    }

    public void limpiar() {
        DateTime fecha_actual = DateTime.Now;
        txtRut.Text = "";
        txtNombres.Text = "";
        txtAP.Text = "";
        txtAM.Text = "";
        calendarioNacimiento.Value = fecha_actual;
        calendarioIngreso.Value = fecha_actual;
        comboCarrera.Text = "";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //lbl.Text = calendarioIngreso.Value.ToShortDateString();
        Alumno nuevo = alumnoNuevo();
        if (a.siExiste(nuevo.Id))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Este alumno ya existe");
        }
        else {
            a.addAlumno(nuevo);
            MessageBox.Show("Alumno Ingresado");
            blocDesbloc(false);
            limpiar();
        }
    }

    private void btn_buscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (a.siExiste(txtRut.Text))
        {
            mostrarUno(txtRut.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Este alumno ya existe");
        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("Ingreso disponible");
            blocDesbloc(true);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 a = new Form1();
        a.ShowDialog();
        this.Dispose();
    }
}
```

el otro form solo tiene esto

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        P_Alumno a = new P_Alumno();// form ingreso alumno
        a.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: Agrega por favor la informacion del otro form tambien. Evidentemente tu informacion vive solo en el form donde cargas los datos. Se podria solucionar comaprtiendo la misma clase entre los dos.

Comment: Lo mejor que puedes hacer es utilizar un evento, es la manera mas efectiva y elegante. Puedes hacer saltar el evento a la hora de añadir un alumno y enviar el alumno nuevo al primer formulario y añadirlo a la lista que ya tienes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Si consideramos el formulario un objeto, las variables de clase desaparecen cuando ese objeto desaparece.

Una solución consiste en recurrir a una de las denostadas variables globales. Declara una variable global en un módulo (puede llamarse, por ejemplo, gList). Dale a esa variable el valor de la lista. Mientras no cierres esa aplicación o alteres su valor mediante una instrucción, esa variable mantendrá su valor y podrás leerlo.

Otra solución es añadir a tu formulario un evento que envíe el valor de la lista a algún sitio antes de cerrarse y colocar en tu aplicación otro objeto que responda a ese evento y reciba el valor de la lista.

Los miembros de la clase Form se enumeran en el siguiente enlace: [clase Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) Los eventos para la clase Form se enumeran en la siguiente lista: [eventos para la clase Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#Eventos)

El evento FormClosing se produce antes de que el formulario se cierre: [evento FormClosing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx)

Si la ejecución de una aplicación termina cuando se cierran todas las ventanas, aunque un formulario se cierre, siempre habrá otro abierto y es posible guardar la lista en él. Añadir al formulario una propiedad que represente la lista y a la que puedan acceder otros formularios puede ser una buena idea.

Si hablamos de lo que pasará con los datos cuando termine la ejecución de la aplicación, hablamos de persistencia. Si queremos que esos datos sigan disponibles, tenemos que guardarlos en algún fichero. Puede ser en una base de datos o en otro tipo de fichero. JSON o XML son formatos de fichero muy extendidas y relativamente fáciles de manejar. Antiguamente se usaban mucho los CSV; pero JSON y XML son formatos más modernos.

Agradezco a la comunidad stackoverflow su apoyo a esta solución que no es necesariamente la mejor. ¡Me gusta mucho aprender de los demás!

Comment: Hola. Las variables globales no son una buena idea. un evento suena muy complicado. Se agradece tu esfuerzo, pero que tal si esperamos que aclare bien sus dudas, muestre su código y podamos ayudarla con lo que tiene, mas que con una explicacion teorica? Gracias!

Comment: Si no eres capaz de proponer alguna solución mejor, no deberías calificar mal mi respuesta: estoy aportando algo mejor que los demás (no hay otras respuestas).

Comment: Hola. No fue mi intencion calificar tu respuesta. Es mas no vote ni en contra ni a favor de ella. Solo aclare q a veces es bueno esperar a ver que hizo OP antes de esbozar una respuesta. Fijate que por eso se le dejaron tantos comentarios. Ahora con lo que agrego si puedes construir una respuesta que sirva. (Y agregar ejemplps de esas practicas si quieres.)

Comment: Estoy trabajando sobre el tema y ampliando mi respuesta. ¡Gracias por leer mi aportación! Tengo que buscar tiempo para leer tu página en stackoverflow que me parece más que interesante.

Comment: A mi también me pareció inadecuado descalificar una solución dada. quizás no es la mejor. Pero es una solución y de hecho yo lo hacia así y funcionaba. Tal y como plantea la pregunta me parece que es una buena solución. Creo que lo que tiene problema es la forma en que planea hacer funcionar el software por parte de quien pregunta. De hecho esa forma se usa en servidores y las llaman variables de aplicación y sesión. Yo lo haría en el caso actual usando parámetros de clase. instancia la clase del formulario destino y le envió un parámetro al constructor del formulario destino

Comment: Crea una propiedad en el formulario donde creas la lista cuyo valor sea esa lista así mientras tengas acceso a este formulario podrás trabajar con la lista

Answer (score 1):

Si entendi bien, quieres llenar los datos de la lista en un formulario diferente a donde instancias la lista y asumo que estas progrmando sobre winforms, en ese caso en tu formulario principal:

Tu formulario donde llenas los datos:

```
    public partial class P_Alumno : Form
    {
        Carrera c = new Carrera();
        private Alumno _listaAlumno

        public P_Alumno(Alumno _ListaAlumno)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Recivimos la instancia de Alumno del formulario principal
            _listaAlumno = _ListaAlumno;
            comboCarrera.DataSource = Carrera.Carreras;
            comboCarrera.DisplayMember = "Descripcion";
        }
        //.......
        //.......

        //No es necesario instanciar el formulario principal de nuevo ya que no lo cierras 
        //y si lo reinstancias perderas los cambios realizados.


        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.close();
        }
    }
```

Y en tu formulario principal:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Alumno listaAlumno = new Alumno(); // Lista Formulario principal
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        P_Alumno a = new P_Alumno(listaAlumno );// form ingreso alumno
        a.ShowDialog();
    }
 }
```

> El objetivo es pasar la lista instanciada en tu formulario principal
>   al formulario de llenado de datos para que las operaciones realizadas
>   en el formulario de datos se reflejen en tu formulario principal

Comment: Es al revés, el principal solo tiene un boton, cuando hago click en ese boton, me abre la ventana en donde ingreso al nuevo(s) alumno(s) a la lista, cuando termino de ingresar, tengo un boton que dice salir que me lleva de regreso a la anterior(la que solo tiene un boton), ahora en la del botón doy a abrir otra vez la de ingreso, pero ya los datos desaparecieron, la idea es que no desaparezcan y que pueda ir y volver

Comment: @EmeLisenokVolka el principio es el mismo solo que invertimos el lugar de la instancia y donde pasamos el parametro

Answer (score 1):

Lo único que tienes que hacer es pasar la referencia de la lista de un formulario al otro, antes de cerrar el formulario que inicializa la lista.

Por ejemplo:

```
FormDestino.ListaAlumnos = FormOrigen.ListaAlumnos
```

Después de eso, ya puedes cerrar el FormOrigen y el destino mantendrá la instancia de la lista.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y gracias por tu respuesta. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: Como es que hago eso?, no encuentro la forma :/

Answer (score 0):

Realmente muchas gracias  a todos, es la primara vez que hacia una pregunta aquí aveces entraba para resolver algunas dudas, ya encontré la solución y era muy simple la verdad, no pensé que era por eso, por lo cual nunca modifique esa parte del código, lo que hice fue declarar la variable como

```
 static List<Alumno> Alumnos = new Lista<Alumno>();
```

y sacarle el new List del constructor 
:c